# node-sass to dart-sass How to compile and watch changes in mypath/folder containing many sass files to a single file

Tags: sass, package.json, node-sass, dart-sass

I was using node-sass and just now started to using dart sass and i want to ask how can i compile and watch a folder to a single file?

I was using this commands in scripts on package.json and worked:

```
"scss": "node-sass -o . src/scss",
"build": "npm run scss",
"watch:css": "node-sass --watch src/scss -o .",
"watch": "npm run watch:css",
"script": "npm run build && npm run watch"
```

but now after i installed sass and uninstall node-sass i am using:

```
"scss": "sass src/scss .",
"build": "npm run scss",
"watch:css": "sass --watch src/scss .",
"watch": "npm run watch:css",
"script": "npm run build && npm run watch"
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who want help to this answer, i managed to solve it this way:

```
"scss": "sass assets/scss:.",
"build": "npm run scss",
"watch:css": "sass --watch assets/scss:.",
"watch": "npm run watch:css",
"script": "npm run build && npm run watch"
```